# Is there ever a reason to continue to sell lower value goods?

Tags: ninja-village

Now that I can make bean soup in my tea shop, is there a reason I shouldn't switch all my shops over to that instead of selling rice cakes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, there is.

In the example for the original question, no since both items consume 1 food item to make.  However, later on high tier items consume more resources to make and your production may not keep up with the demand so you may not want to ramp up all your shops to the maximum high tier item immediately.